# Menu lateral responsivo com botão

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um menu lateral:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de colocar um botão para esconder e mostrar esse menu, e que quando eu diminua a resolução apareça esse botão para que eu possa exibi-lo.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <!-- Sidebar -->
   <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
         <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <img src="upload/users/{{user.usuario.foto}}" class="img-responsive img-arredondadaSide" alt="Responsive image"/>      
         </li>
         </br>
         </br>
         </br>
         <li class="active">
            <a href="#/home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#configuracoes" role="button" 
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ng-if="user.usuario.permissao ==1"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Configurações <span class="caret">
            </span></a>
            <ul id="configuracoes" class="collapse">
               <li>
                  <a href="#/usuario">Usuários</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 220px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

Exemplo que estou utilizando: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente eu faço assim. Crio uma classe que esconde o MENU, por assim dizer, a esquerda da tela usando o `transformX`. Lembre de colocar o `-webkit`, `moz-` e `o-` nessa propriedade.

E uma função jQuery para ativar a classe. Cria um botão com a classe `close-menu` fora do MENU, óbvio, se não ele esconde junto. Coloca do lado esquerdo de **ORÁCULO** só para você testar.

### CSS

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.close{
    transform: translateX(80%); /* Coloca aqui o tamanho - width do seu menu em PX */
}
```

### jQuery

```
$('.close-menu').on('mousedown', function(){
    // Aqui é no MAIN
    $('main').toggleClass('close-menu');
});
```

### Media Query Até 768

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    #sidebar-wrapper{
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

No seu caso a class `.close` é no MAIN. Não sei se tem um `<main>` no seu site. 
Mas caso não tenha, essa classe tem que ser aplicada na `div` que envolve seu site. Não o `body`.

Comment: Quando faço `transform: translateX(-100%);` na Media Query o menu não aparece mais

Comment: Dentro da média só coloquei `transform: translateX(-100%);`

Comment: #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 220px;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

Comment: Ignora meu comentário anterior. A classe `close` não pode estar em nenhuma `media`, tem que estar fora. Tem que ser global. Agora, tem que debugar pelo Inspect Element o motivo de você estar clicando e não estar abrindo.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar

Comment: Editei meu post. A classe `close` tem que ser aplicada no `main`. E editei o código também. Veja que tem um comentário...

Answer (score 1):

Eis aqui que você precisa adotar a tendência do menu "hamburger" (aquele com três linhas) ou algo parecido. Você deixa ele por padrão escondido, mas quando a tela possuir uma determinada largura você pode exibi-lo.
No seu caso, você pode beneficiar-se de "CSS Media Queries" - e é exatamente como seu template faz atualmente.
Então isso seria simples:

No HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <a id="menu-toggle" href="#menu">
            MENU
        </a>
    ...
```

no lado do CSS:

```
#menu-toggle {
    display: none; 
}
@media(max-width:767px) {       

    #menu-toggle {
        display: block; 
    }
}
```

`max-width: 767px` ali quer dizer que a condição para que esse botão/ícone menu aparecer, a deve tela precisa ter no máximo `767px` de largura. Por que `767px`? Esse valor foi escolhido porque sabemos (veja o CSS do template) que a partir de 768px o template já mostra o sidebar (e o menu, portanto) por padrão.

No lado do javascript nós já temos uma rotina do próprio template, então não deve alterar nada (exceto se você removeu isso ou alterou o que veio com o template):

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>
```

E uma amostra funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/krx61hh9/embedded/result/

Comment: Fiz um teste e o <a>menu</a> aparece apenas quando o menu some, porém quando clico nele o menu não é aberto.

Comment: @Techies Rapaz, acho que falta boa vontade de sua parte.

Comment: Claro, com certeza @felipsmartins